# HttpClientModule ( HTTPClient ) Error Handling for Angular 4.3 and above

Tags: http, httpclient, angular5

I have a scenario of logging the request payload on error response but error object cannot contain more info than its default members.

Any suggestion apart from creating a closure object for payload and use it in error callback ?

I doubt to add new member in this existing Error Class

```
export declare class HttpErrorResponse extends HttpResponseBase implements Error {
readonly name: string;
readonly message: string;
readonly error: any | null;
/**
 * Errors are never okay, even when the status code is in the 2xx success range.
 */
readonly ok: boolean;
constructor(init: {
    error?: any;
    headers?: HttpHeaders;
    status?: number;
    statusText?: string;
    url?: string;


});
```

}

Angular 4.3: HttpClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
We need to intercept the error message and add access payload from that and pass on to error object.

```
error.payload = request.data
```